# Get a map of specific qualifiers and its value

Tags: java, hbase

Examples of what I have:

```
0:a.b.c = "...";
0:a.b.d = "...";
0:a.e   = "...";
```

I'm using Hbase client from org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.

If I do a query as

```
get.addFamily("0");
get.addColumn("a");
```

Will it be possible for me to get a map from the result as:

```
<"b.c","...">
<"b.d","...">
<"e"  ,"...">
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you elaborate your quotations in brief

Answer (score 0):

**What you need is `ColumnPrefixFilter`**. Here is a simple example :

```
    byte[] columnFamily = Bytes.toBytes("0"),
            qualifierPrefix = Bytes.toBytes("a"),
            rowKey = Bytes.toBytes("row-key");

    ColumnPrefixFilter columnPrefixFilter = new ColumnPrefixFilter(qualifierPrefix);

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setFilter(columnPrefixFilter);
    scan.addFamily(columnFamily);
    scan.setStartRow(rowKey);
    scan.setStopRow(rowKey);

    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```